# Select entities by condition column and clarify it by many to many condition

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, criteria, queryover

Select entities by condition column and clarify it by many to many condition

I have followed structure of classes (Entities):

```
class Order {
   ...
   public virtual long OrderId {get; set;}
   public virtual boolean ForFavorites {get; set;}
   public virtual User Owner {get; set;}
   ...
}
class User {
   ...
   public virtual long UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual List<User> Favorites {get; set;}
   public virtual List<User> FavoritesOrderers {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

How to write `QueryOver` or Criteria to get all orders where:

- Order is not marker as `ForFavorites` AND
- Order is marked as `ForFavorites` and some User is in Order.Owner.Favorites?

And opposite way:

How can I write `QueryOver` or Criteria to select all orders where `Order.Owner` in my Favorites?

**--update: add Fluent Mapping**

My mapping:

```
class OrderMap:ClassMap<Order> {

    public OrderMap(){
        Id(x=>x.OrderId).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.ForFavorites);
        References(x => x.Owner, "UserId");
        ...
    }
}

class UserMap:ClassMap<User> {
    public UserMap() {
        Id(x => x.UserId).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Favorites)
            .AsBag()
            .LazyLoad()
            .Table("Favorites")
            .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("FavoriteId")
            .Cascade.All();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.FavoritesOrderers)
            .AsBag()
            .LazyLoad()
            .Table("FavoriteOrderers")
            .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("FavoriteId")
            .Cascade.All();
        ...
    }
}
```

**--update: add some SQL**

SQL may be like this:

`:userId` is id of favorite User

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Order] o
JOIN [User] u ON o.owner = u.userId
WHERE (
    (o.ForFavorites = false) || 
    (o.ForFavorites = true && :userId IN
        (SELECT favoriteId FROM [Favorites] f WHERE (f.UserId = u.userId))
))
```

Are there some other variations with better perfomance?..

For opposite way:

```
SELECT *  
FROM [Order] o
JOIN [User] u ON o.owner = u.userId
INNER JOIN [FavoriteOrderers] fo ON fo.favoriteId=u.userId
WHERE (fo.userId = :userId)
```

Comment: Can you show the SQL you'd like to generate?

Comment: I'm edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a few assumptions about your mappings, but hopefully this will help:

Probably something like this for the first query:

```
session.QueryOver<Order>()
    .JoinQueryOver(o => o.Owner)
    .Where(
        Restrictions.Or(
            Restrictions.Where<Order>(o => !o.ForFavorites),
            Restrictions.And(
                Restrictions.Where<Order>(o => o.ForFavorites),
                Subqueries.In( 
                    userId,
                    QueryOver.Of<Favorite>()
                        .Where(f => f.UserId = userId)
                        .Select(f => f.FavoriteId)
                        .DetachedCriteria))))
    .List<Order>();
```

I omitted the join to `User` since it wasn't used (and you said you wanted all `Order`s meeting the criteria).

Your second query could look like this:

```
session.QueryOver<Order>()
    .JoinQueryOver(o => o.Owner)
    .JoinQueryOver<FavoriteOrderers>(u => u.FavoriteOrderers)
        .Where(fo => fo.UserId == userId)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You push me to solution.
I'm use your solution for search my self. See below.

Answer (score 1):

After good response I found my solution, because in response poster uses own assumption on mappings, 
which aren't right in my case, but may be better.

```
session.QueryOver<Order>()
    .JoinAlias(o => o.Owner, () => owner)
    .Where(
        Restrictions.Or(
            Restrictions.Where<Order>(o => !o.ForFavorites),
            Restrictions.And(
                Restrictions.Where<Order>(o => o.ForFavorites),
                Subqueries.In( 
                    userId,
                    QueryOver.Of<User>()
                        .Where(f => f.UserId = owner.UserId)
                        .JoinQueryOver<User>(u => u.Favorite, () => fav)
                        .Select(f => f.FavoriteId)
                       .DetachedCriteria))))
    .List<Order>();
```